# Multiple gcc on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, path, c++, make

I did a port install for gcc `version 4.7.1 (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.1_2)` 
I named the executable as g+ and placed it in one my $PATH.
I use gcc 4.7.1 when I need c++11 standard. I haven't changed the original g++ so as not messup
XCode.

I am using eclipse-cdt and running the make all from the window. It's giving me:

```
20:12:40 **** Build of configuration Default for project 2804-hw2 ****
make all 
g+ -c -Wall -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.o
make: g+: No such file or directory
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
20:12:40 Build Finished (took 89ms)
```

Here is my makefile

```
CC=g++-mp-4.7
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp Vector3D.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=exec
PATH := ${PATH}:/opt/local/bin/

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
    echo ${PATH}
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
 clean:
    rm $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJECTS)
```

How do I make eclipse detect my g+?

Comment: Put something like `echo ${PATH}` in there and see if it got your path. If not, add a `PATH += ...` line to your makefile.

Comment: I added the path, it's still not able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a link to g++-mp-4.7 in my /usr/bin. You can't seem to append to the path in Eclipse's make. It didn't work. Making a link works.